sqlalchemy many to many connection ambiguous foreign keys error
I have an sqlite database within which I am creating several tables. One has a many to many relation though a joining table with another. Upon querying either table for its association, I get sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Characters.associated_attributes - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'joinerCharactersToAttributes'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables.
I know that this is a problem with the association, but I cannot figure out how my code deviates from the documentation enough to throw this error.
I have tried many variations on the foreign_keys attribute, but I cannot get past this error. The code to create my tables is below:
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


character_attributes_joiner = Table(
    'joinerCharactersToAttributes',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('char_id', ForeignKey('normalizedCharacters.character_id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('attr_key', ForeignKey('normalizedAttributes.attribute_key'), primary_key=True),
    Column('attr_id', ForeignKey('normalizedAttributes.attribute_id'), primary_key=True)
)


class Guilds(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'normalizedGuilds'
    guild_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    associated_characters:Mapped[List['Characters']] = relationship(back_populates='guild')


class Characters(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'normalizedCharacters'
    character_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    character_name:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    guild_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('normalizedGuilds.guild_id'), nullable=False)
    character_type:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)

    guild:Mapped['Guilds'] = relationship(back_populates='associated_characters', foreign_keys=[guild_id])

    associated_attributes:Mapped[List['Attributes']] = relationship('Attributes', secondary=character_attributes_joiner, back_populates='associated_characters', foreign_keys=[character_attributes_joiner.c.attr_key, character_attributes_joiner.c.attr_id])


class Attributes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'normalizedAttributes'
    attribute_key:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    attribute_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    level:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    is_leaf:Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    parent_key:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('normalizedAttributes.attribute_key'), nullable=True)
    parent_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('normalizedAttributes.attribute_id'), nullable=True)

    parent = relationship('Attributes', remote_side=[attribute_key, attribute_id])
    associated_characters:Mapped[List['Characters']] =  relationship('Characters', secondary=character_attributes_joiner, back_populates='associated_attributes', foreign_keys=[character_attributes_joiner.c.char_id])


Upon querying the Characters object to find the associated attributes with said character:
with engine.connect() as conn:
    statement = select(Characters.associated_attributes)
    result = conn.execute(statement)

I get a sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError. I can see in the documentation where this is referenced, however I cannot for the life of me figure out where my code deviates from that process.
Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.
